# Why are elements missing when calling `validation_step` in Pytorch Lightning?

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I have a dataset with 20 rows and I set

```py
eval_batch_size=10
num_train_epochs=1
```

Thats my validation_step

```py
def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    print(len(batch[elements]))
```

What I expect to see is that the number of elements in one batch is always 10 because a dataset of size 20 in two batches is twice 10 but in the last print I get 8 for the length of the elements. Why are two elements missing?

**EDIT**

When tokenizing my dataset two rows of the dataset are going lost, this is why.

Comment: Can you specify the dataset a bit more? Or at least explain what you are doing

Comment: Please provide the code of your dataloader/dataset class.